# EmberJs; conditionally start instance initializer

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is it possible to conditionally run an instance initializer based on an environment variable?

The use case: I have an Ember app running on my local machine. If a certain environment variable is present when the app starts, I want to start a service called "lights". If it's not present I do not want the service to run.

```
//instance-intializers/lights.js
 export default {
  name: 'lights',
  initialize(application) {
  application.container.lookup('service:lights');
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way is to remove it from build. (As Lux mentioned in his answer.)

A quick way is to get environment variable and do a check such as :

```
//instance-intializers/lights.js
export default {
  name: 'lights',
  initialize(application) {
    let env = application.resolveRegistration('config:environment');
    if(env === ''){
      application.lookup('service:lights');
      //... do whatever you want...
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Depends on what he means by `environment variable`. His question sounded like he means an system environment-variable that he can set in his shell, which is odd, but a bit more tricky then something from the config.

Comment: Then where is the environment variable put? Client or server? Maybe its my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to detect the environment variable during the build thats not really that hard. You could just write an in-repo-addon and use the [preprocessTree](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Addon.html#method_preprocessTree) hook to add or remove the initializer. There you are in node env, so you have access to everything you need.